# Color Scheme name for <?php tags in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

I've been messing around with my color scheme and now I can't figure this out:

How do I go about changing the color that `<?php` will show up in my .php files?

I've done a lot of googling and some trial-and-error but I'm hoping someone here might know off the top of their head.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the Notepad++ theme (with a little adjustment to the font style for my own likings), which should do the trick

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Meta Brace</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>punctuation.section.embedded -(source string source punctuation.section.embedded), meta.brace.erb.html</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string>bold</string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#F02A1D</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```